# 'There is an error in XML document (30, 10)' error while returning difference type from XML element type

Tags: c#, xml, mapping, xml-deserialization

I have a XML file. I want map it to an object. one of xml elements is string and I want to convert this string to int value of an Enum in set section of property. then return this int value, but when file reader want to deserialize my XML file to object, I get runtime error which says "There is an error in XML document (30, 10)".

```
private int processCodeInt;
    [XmlElement("ProcessCode")]
    public int ProcessCode
    {
        get { return this.processCodeInt; }
        set
        {
            var temp = typeof(Common.Transaction.Definition_Transaction.Def_TrxType_Detail)
                .GetMembers().Where(i => i.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field).ToList();
            this.processCodeInt = Convert.ToInt32(temp.Where(u => u.Name == value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Thank you all.

in follow I leave my codes:

Mapping classes:

```
[XmlRoot("Model")]
    public class Model
    {
        [XmlElement("Transaction")]
        public List<Transaction> Transactions;
    }
    public class Transaction
    {
        [XmlElement("Message")]
        public List<Message> Messages;
    }
    public class Message
    {
        [XmlElement("In")]
        public MessageType In { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Out")]
        public MessageType Out { get; set; }
    }
    public class MessageType
    {
        [XmlElement("ChannelType")]
        public int ChannelType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TransactionType")]
        public int TransactionType { get; set; }
        private int processCodeInt;
        [XmlElement("ProcessCode")]
        public int ProcessCode
        {
            get { return this.processCodeInt; }
            set
            {
                var temp = typeof(Common.Transaction.Definition_Transaction.Def_TrxType_Detail)
                    .GetMembers().Where(i => i.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field).ToList();
                temp.RemoveAt(0);
                MemberInfo[] processCodeMemberInfos = temp.ToArray();
                this.processCodeInt = Convert.ToInt32(processCodeMemberInfos.Where(u => u.Name == value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().ToString());

            }
        }
        [XmlElement("IsExpired")]
        public bool IsExpired { get; set; }
    }
```

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Model>
  <Transaction>
    <Message>
      <In>
        <ChannelType>0</ChannelType>
        <TransactionType>1</TransactionType>
        <ProcessCode>Balance</ProcessCode>
        <IsExpired>0</IsExpired>
      </In>
      <Out>
        <ChannelType>1</ChannelType>
        <TransactionType>1</TransactionType>
        <ProcessCode>Balance</ProcessCode>
        <IsExpired>0</IsExpired>
      </Out>
    </Message>
  </Transaction>
</Model>
```

Mapping Code:

```
var TransactionModelsFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
            +@"/TransactionModels.xml");
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
            overview = (Model)reader.Deserialize(TransactionModelsFile);
            TransactionModelsFile.Close();
```

Comment: Why `ProcessCode` is `int` while the actual value is `Balance`?

Comment: @Alex thank u for your comment, please see the set part of processcode property, I want to convert Enum string value to Int of that member.

Comment: You can do anything, but `ProcessCode` is int so your code won't be called until value is `string`. So use Enums (AFAIK they are deserialized properly by their name), or string and then use your getters and setters to get a result.

Comment: You said 'your code won't be called until value is string', of course I know it can not with this structure which I mentioned above, but exactly my question is finding a solution for this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see I just added `Enum` instead of string because `Balance` is not a valid value for an `int` field. But if you want to store it as integer, so I use backing field in this case.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
        using (var fs = new FileStream("source.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var obj = (Model) ser.Deserialize(fs);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Transactions[0].Messages[0].In.ProcessCode);
        }
    }
}


public class Model
{
    [XmlElement("Transaction")]
    public List<Transaction> Transactions;
}
public class Transaction
{
    [XmlElement("Message")]
    public List<Message> Messages;
}
public class Message
{
    public MessageType In { get; set; }
    public MessageType Out { get; set; }
}

public class MessageType
{
    public int ChannelType { get; set; }
    public int TransactionType { get; set; }
    private int processCodeInt;

    public ProcessCode ProcessCode
    {
        get { return (ProcessCode) processCodeInt; }
        set { processCodeInt = (int) value; }
    }
    public bool IsExpired { get; set; }
}

public enum ProcessCode
{
    Balance
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you test it @Alex Zhukovskiy? :)

Comment: @vahidkargar yes, and I get expected output.

Comment: good job @Alex Zhukovski, Thank you for your effort for helping me. accepting answer and +1 is least things which I can do for gratitude.

Comment: @vahidkargar just use appropriate types, C# is strongly types language so it helps you to find such mistakes. And I don't think that you should leave an `int` field, becuase `Enum`s are quite easy to cast to `int`.

Comment: Performance is very very important for me, although casting to int with (int) havent bad performance, Anyway your answer help me, and Thank U.

Comment: @vahidkargar you are wrong. Castng enum to `int` cost nothing. Please, show an example, where your performance suffer becuase of `int` casting?

Comment: I said not bad, means it is ok casting enum to int.